# Pandas forward fill parts of column that break order

Tags: python, sorting, pandas

I think this will be easy, but I can't think of the right way. I basically want a column to be sorted from smallest to largest, but I don't actually want to sort these, I want to replace values that are "wrong" in the sort. The DataFrame is already sorted how it needs to be, I just need to replace some values that this 'id' column has wrong.

Best way to understand is an example:

```
In [98]: d = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({1: {'id': 2}, 2: {'id': 2}, 3: {'id': 3}, 4: {'id':3}, 5: {'id':2}, 6: {'id': 2}, 7: {'id': 4}, 8: {'id': 5}, 9: {'id': 4}, 10: {'id': 6}}, orient='index')

In [99]: d
Out[99]:
    id
1    2
2    2
3    3
4    3
5    2
6    2
7    4
8    5
9    4
10   6
```

Now you can see this isn't quite ordered. What I want the output to be is this:

```
Out[101]:
    id
1    2
2    2
3    3
4    3
5    3
6    3
7    4
8    5
9    5
10   6
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, aren't you simply looking for the cumulative maximum?

```
>>> d["fixed_id"] = d["id"].cummax()
>>> d
    id  fixed_id
1    2         2
2    2         2
3    3         3
4    3         3
5    2         3
6    2         3
7    4         4
8    5         5
9    4         5
10   6         6
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html#pandas.Series.diff) to find where the values are not equal or increasing, set these to `NaN` and then call `ffill`:

```
In [252]:
d.loc[d['id'].diff() < 0, 'id'] = np.NaN
d['id'] = d['id'].ffill()
d

Out[252]:
    id
1    2
2    2
3    3
4    3
5    3
6    4
7    4
8    5
9    5
10   6
```

**UPDATE**

You can use double square brackets to force `apply` to be called on a `df`, this allows you operate row-wise, then use a user defined func to compare the current row value against all row values prior to current row, this generates a boolean mask to select the invalid rows and assign `NaN` to these and then `ffill`:

```
In [293]:
def func(x):
    return (d['id'].iloc[0:x.name] > x[0]).any()
d.loc[d[['id']].apply(func, axis=1), 'id'] = np.NaN
d['id'] = d['id'].ffill()
d

Out[293]:
    id
1    2
2    2
3    3
4    3
5    3
6    3
7    4
8    5
9    5
10   6
```

Comment: Hey, I made an edit to the file. There could be repeating "wrong" entries in the dataframe, where we have multiple out of order in a row. I had thought of shift() and diff(), but realized this would have to be recursive if there were multiple and I didn't know how many there were.

Comment: It is normal etiquette to fully state your requirements upfront rather than posting a basic example and then posting an edit where you state what your *real* problem is, this wastes everyone's time and is very annoying

Comment: I obviously forgot and did not do it intentionally. I do apologize, though.